How to balance tire rolling resistance against puncture proofness
As tire pressure affects rolling resistance, so too does the load on the tire.  I believe bicyclerollingresistance.com (BRR) indicates the load placed on the tire during testing.
So:

given identical tires, the rolling resistance of the front tire will be lower than the rear as most of the load is carried by the real wheel of the bike.
the rolling resistance of each wheel then changes when descending or climbing as the load changes on the wheel, the net effect would remain the same.
would the rolling resistance be roughly equivalent to the wear rate of the tire?  The rear tire wears faster than the front possibly because more energy is dissipated through the tire through pedaling and flexion of the tire itself from the load placed on it as it rolls.

If I am trying to effectively balance puncture resistance of the front tire and rear tire, would it be worthwhile to use the ratio of wear front versus rear multiplied with the rear tire score to determine roughly the puncture resistance needed from the front tire to be equivalent to the rear tire?  These numbers don't have any units attached, so I really mean to use them as a grain of salt.
So, if according to https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/the-test#puncture-resistance the rear tire has a puncture resistance of 100 and the front tire wears about half the rate of the rear, then I should look for a tire with a puncture resistance of 50 to be comparable to the rear tire?
My reasoning for this is that I want to optimize the risk in this case.  I've had few front flats, mostly rear.  The worst possible time to get a flat would be while descending at speed approaching a turn.  And, while I could get the same front tire as the rear, in my experience, it takes quite a bit more to get a flat front tire and of all the front flats I've had, they've take some time to go flat.

Have you found tires that have numeric puncture resistance ratings? If so I'm curious which ones and what they base it on.

@DavidD https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/the-test#puncture-resistance

@Rеnаud Thank you - so it's the rolling resistance website that has a puncture rating. The metric is "TPS = sharp + blunt + ((sharp + blunt) * thickness * 0.5)"

I will use the same tires front and rear.  While the rolling resistance of the front tire will be lower since there is a lower load on it with a lower tire pressure, the marginal gains of selecting a tire with less flat protection on the front will be minimal.

And if you get a flat on the front at speed, control is immediately compromised.     Not recommended.


I am not sure your reasoning (or conclusion?) is correct since a lot of people (including me) inflate the rear tire to a higher pressure to compensate for the difference in load. This significantly affects rolling resistance.

I doubt it to be that straight forward. The rear tire wears faster, at least partly, because the rear wheel is connected to the power source. Some people, including me, also prefer to brake more on the rear wheel. So breaking preference will also significantly affect wear pattern.


I think you are going into a rabbit hole here trying to quantify what puncture protection is "needed" front vs rear. But I will easily admit the rear tire is more prone to punctures in my experience.


exactly, where do you think that wear comes from, that is also what it costs us to roll the tire.  That is taken directly from BRR, as the load on the tire increases, so does its rolling resistance.  Yes, air pressure also influences the resistance, as the pressure increases, the tire deforms less.  2. yes, I most certainly agree the rear is more prone to punctures because there is considerably more force on it.


I don't understand if you have a disagreement here or not. I don't think it is fair to include wear due to accelerating (breaking or providing power) in the term "rolling resistance". Sure it is friction, but I would not categorize it as rolling resistance as it is not due to simply rolling along. The caused wear would instead depend largely on how you ride and not on the tire itself. Thus my disagreement with your third point.

I'm not "breaking" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking, but instead braking by applying the brakes.  I'm not sure if you meant I was doing some sort of acrobatics on my bike, but that would certainly lead to excessive tire wire.  I'm referring to using wheels and tires in a rolling function.


In theory yes, but the balance of mass front-to-back depends on the type of bike, the riding position, and everything on the bike. For example, a TT bike with no gear on it and a rider riding in a typical position for TT riding actually will usually have an almost exactly 50/50 distribution of weight front-to-back (because, interestingly enough, this actually helps with efficiency rather significantly). In contrast, with a typical MTB the ratio is usually around 35-40/65-60 front/back (because higher load on the rear wheel helps you actually get going and the aggressive tires used for mountain biking can help make up the traction difference for the front). Hybrid, CX, road, and commuter bikes tend to be somewhere between an MTB and TT bike. E-bikes tend to be closer to MTBs than hybrid or road bikes, and elongated cargo bikes tend to have most of their weight on the end of the bike that doesn’t have the cargo tray (so you get a more even balance when they’re loaded). Additionally, and just as importantly, it’s very normal to use a higher tire pressure in the rear wheel to offset the higher loading of the wheel (effectively, to make the contact area closer to the same for the two tires), which further mitigates the weight difference.
To some extent yes, but the practical impact is negligible unless you’re dealing with either a huge amount of mass on the bike or a very steep incline. Furthermore, if you’re riding symmetrical routes (that is, you’re riding back the way you came, or the whole route has a net elevation change of 0), that will offset the impact this has on tire wear. In essence, unless you’re racing in atypical conditions or are bikepacking in absurdly rugged terrain, you can completely ignore this.
No, because there are other differences. Most (but not all) of why the rear wheel wears faster is not because of any difference in rolling resistance, it’s because the rear wheel is actively pushing everything, while the front is not. In other words, there is far more energy going into the contact area of the rear wheel than there is going into the contact area of the front wheel when you’re just pedaling along. Rolling resistance does have some impact on wear rate, but it’s negligible compared to loading of the wheel and energy input through the drive-train (and, for that matter, the surface conditions you’re cycling on).



If I am trying to balance puncture resistance of the front tire and rear tire, would it be accurate to use the ratio of wear front versus rear multiplied with the rear tire score to determine roughly the puncture resistance needed from the front tire to be equivalent to the rear tire? So, if the rear tire has a puncture resistance of 100 and the front tire wears about half the rate of the rear, then I should look for a tire with a puncture resistance of 50 to be comparable to the rear tire?

It sounds like you might be trying to avoid ‘wasting’ some of the serviceable life of the front tire. This is admirable to some extent, but it also ignores the fact that having a good front tire is significantly more important for cycling safely than having a good rear tire. Your front tire takes more than half of the braking load (so poor traction there makes a bike much harder to stop than poor traction with a rear tire does), and it is responsible for 100% of steering (so poor traction there makes it riskier to take aggressive corners, and in turn harder to safely dodge an oncoming collision).

Good points, I wanted to see what others thought about tire wear.  I probably will go with the same front tire as the rear, but would consider more of a race tire for the front and a touring tire for the rear.  I will certainly wear the front tire down, I won't change the tire until it is needed (independent of what the other tire is doing) but yeah, safety first.

A tire with less flat protection generally grips better, wears faster, and rolls faster than a tire with more flat protection.  I had a Bontrager Hard Case lite that rolls rather fast, but its flat protection is not that great and it wears rather quickly, but it is fairly comfortable as it absorbs much road noise.  Most of my flats have been on the rear tire.  No, with having a faster rolling front tire, I'd have less flat protection and in my experience I'm much less likely to get a flat front tire.  It's more about optimizing and balancing risk.

There's a simple solution to avoid wasting tires and having fresh tire in the front: when the rear wears out, move the previous front tire to rear and put a new tire in the front. For cornering you'd want good grip on both tires because fishtailing and highside crashes aren't any more fun than losing traction in the front.

I am not doing any racing, so I don't think I'm close that that limit on grip.  I don't understand how I'd be wasting the tire.  I only replace the tire when it is gone.  Just because the rear tire is gone, doesn't mean I need to replace the front, does it?

@JohnDoe the front tire practically never wears out but eventually turns hard and brittle and has to be replaced. If you rotate the tires, you'll get a bit more miles out of them and have a good tire in the front all the time.

(Partial) frame challenge: don’t balance the puncture protection but have more puncture protection in the front. Rear tyre might be more susceptible to puncture, but puncture in the front tyre, especially one that yields fast deflation of it, is way more dangerous. And as Austin Hemmelgarn points out, weight ratio varies between bike types, and assuming that you have more weight in the rear, the rear tyre dominates the rolling resistance. So having the better-rolling tyre in rear gives you lower rolling resistance than the other way around (I’m assuming here you’re having better-rolling-less-puncture-protection and slower-rolling-more-puncture-protection tyres).
Personally I would always prioritise front wheel protection, more so if that would give less rolling resistance. This is also not too far from how MTBs often have bigger tyres in front than in back. Although there it’s more for the grip than for the puncture protection.
And speaking of grip, Bicycle Rolling Resistance also tests the grip. Do not put significantly slippier tyre in front. If the more grippy tyre has less puncture protection, you must balance the risks yourself.
Or perhaps just put same type of tyre front and back.

The rear tire benefits more from puncture protection and wears faster. Not because of higher wear rate requires more puncture protection. The two effects are independent.
The rear tire wears the fastest because bicycles are rear wheel drive.
The rear tire benefits from more puncture protection than the front, because rear tires puncture more often. Rear tires puncture more often, because most sharp fragments are not sharp end up on pavement. For example, consider a glass fragment. Most likely it's lying on its side. When you ride over it, the front tire touches it first but because it's lying on its side, it doesn't puncture. However, the front tire upsets the glass fragment in such a manner that it's no longer necessarily lying on its side but can be temporarily raised sharp end up. When the rear tire goes over it, the sharp end then punctures the rear tire.
Your theory that puncture score should be twice for rear tire has no theoretical basis. It's just an arbitrary measure, and you can't say that it should be N times more for the rear tire, whatever the value of N is.
For simplicity, I suggest using the same tire rear and front. The reason being is that the front tire wears so slow due to treadwear that it can suffer due to other effects such as reduction of traction due to aging rubber. When you have the same tire rear and front, you can move the old front tire (with still lots of wear life left) to the rear when the rear is fully worn, and then put the new tire to front. The front benefits the most from traction, so having the better tire front is always the best choice.
Rolling resistance doesn't depend on wear rate. The two are independent. Rear wears faster because bicycles are rear wheel drive. If you design a bicycle with odd geometry that places more load on front, then the front would have more rolling resistance but the rear would still wear the fastest, because bicycles are rear wheel drive.
